# Are there any non-supply cards besides Black Market?

Tags: dominion, dominion-promotional

According to the designer of Dominion, [Donald X. Vaccarino](http://forum.dominionstrategy.com/index.php?topic=116.0):

> Bridge makes all cards cheaper, **not just ones in the supply**. This was to prevent problems in weird situations. I am not sure the kind of thing you'd need to get those problems will ever happen, but I knew that this way of doing it meant I was safe. This also allows some unusual combos to work.

Which non-supply cards does he refer to? The only example I can think of is the Black Market.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All cards not in the supply could include:

- Cards in your hand
- Cards in your opponents hand
- Cards in play (including opponents)
- Cards in your deck
- Cards in your opponents deck
- Cards in your discard pile
- Cards in your opponents pile.
- Cards in other locations (ie Village Mat)
- etc.

Example Play from Intrigue cards:

Play a two Mining Villages, play two Bridges, play a Swindler.
Opponent turns over an Estate which is now valued at $0, replace opponent's Estate with a Curse.

Comment: Also, the Prize pile, Madman pile, Mercenary pile, and Spoils pile are all not part of the supply. Of course, these aren't the cards that Bridge rule had in mind.

Comment: As of the release of Adventures, there are also the Traveller upgrade lines, which have non-zero costs so they would be affected by cost reduction as well. (Events, since they're not cards, are not affected.)